# Разделение чисел при загрузке csv python

Tags: python, csv

Необходимо, чтобы при загрузке CSV в программу, она верно разделяла числа. Пока она разделяет так,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А необходимо, чтобы разделяла так,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код загрузки CSV

```
path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open CSV', os.getenv('HOME'), 'CSV(*.csv)')[0]
print(path)
temp_data = pd.read_csv(path,nrows=1,sep=',', decimal = ',', engine="python")
temp_data2 = pd.read_csv(path, nrows=1, sep=';', decimal=',', engine="python")
if temp_data.shape[1]>temp_data2.shape[1]: self.all_data=pd.read_csv(path,sep=',', decimal=',', engine="python")
else: self.all_data=pd.read_csv(path,sep=';', decimal=',', engine="python")
```

Не понимаю, почему не работает, ведь указал разделитель как ',', подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: а в самом csv что?

Comment: @strawdog, не понял вопроса), числа дробные, разделенные запятой, если указать разделитель не запятой, а точкой, то все отлично, но необходимо, чтобы и запятую считывал верно

Comment: Везде `sep=';'` сделайте. По первому скриншоту очевидно, что у вас разделитель ячеек - точка с запятой. Вот тут вообще не понятно как у вас должно работать, когда разделитель ячеек и дробной части указан один и тот же: `temp_data = pd.read_csv(path,nrows=1,sep=',', decimal = ',', engine="python")`

Comment: Да, это работает. Но тогда перестают загружаться csv файлы в которых, sep = ',', необходимо чтобы программа работала и с sep = ',' и с sep = ';'

Comment: @CatBa-dum-tss Ну надо как-то эти файлы отделить и загружать по-другому

Comment: @CatBa-dum-tss одинаково загружать файлы с разным разделителем не получится. Либо приведите к одному виду все, либо как-то хитро вычисляйте, какие разделители используются.